# Using Windows.Media.Audio to play more sound files on top of each other UWP

Tags: c#, audio, uwp

Is there a way I can use Windows.Media.Audio to play more sound files at once (overlapping over each other). The only samples I've been able to find do not demonstrate such a problem (https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation/cs/AudioCreation

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample 4 in the [Audio Creation example](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/AudioCreation) is what you're looking for; submix nodes.